# How to add data validation in already existing file using java apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a xls files to which i need to add a data validation (comboboxes) for some cells using java.Hwen i am trying to add validation for column for existing/already exist file ist not working.

But when i am generating new xls file and adding data validation using same code is working fine.

Any Suggestion/Idea???

I am working on linux. Below is my code:-

```
 FileInputStream fsip = new FileInputStream(new File(existingPath)); 
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsip); 

worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);  
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList( 3,5,1,1); 

DVConstraint dvConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint( new String[]{"10", "20", "30"}); 

HSSFDataValidation dataValidation = new HSSFDataValidation (addressList, dvConstraint);
worksheet.addValidationData(dataValidation); 

fsip.close(); 

FileOutputStream Ofile = new FileOutputStream(new File(newPath)); 

workbook.write(Ofile); 

Ofile.close();
```

Comment: What exactly "is not working"? You can type values other than "10", "20" or "30" in cells B4 - B6 of the second sheet of your workbook? Or the dropdown does not appear? If the latter, what about `dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(false);`?

Comment: I can type any values in cells B4-B6 of the second sheet and drop down also not appearing over there.